# Why do I get different weights when using TensorFlow for multiple linear regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression

I have two implementations of multiple linear regressions, one using `tensorflow` and one using only `numpy`. I generate a dummy set of data and I try to recover the weights I used, but although the `numpy` one returns the initial weights, the `tensorflow` one always returns different weights (which also sort of work)

The `numpy` implementation is [here](http://pastebin.com/LMM1fju0), and here's the TF implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.array([[i, i + 10] for i in range(100)]).astype(np.float32)
y = np.array([i * 0.4 + j * 0.9 + 1 for i, j in x]).astype(np.float32)

# Add bias
x = np.hstack((x, np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)))).astype(np.float32)

# Create variable for weights
n_features = x.shape[1]
np.random.rand(n_features)
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features, 1]))
w = tf.Print(w, [w])

# Loss function
y_hat = tf.matmul(x, w)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y, y_hat)))

operation = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.000001).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for iteration in range(5000):
        session.run(operation)
    weights = w.eval()
    print(weights)
```

Running the script gets me weights around `[-0.481, 1.403, 0.701]`, while running the `numpy` version gets me weights around `[0.392, 0.907, 0.9288]` which are much closer to the weights I used to generate the data: `[0.4, 0.9, 1]`

Both learning rates/epochs parameters are the same, and both initialise weights randomly. I don't normalize the data for either of the implementations, and I've ran them multiple times.

Why are the results different? I also tried to initialise weights in the TF version using `w = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(n_features).reshape(n_features,1).astype(np.float32))` but that didn't fix it either. Is there something wrong with the TF implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with broadcasting. The shape of `y_hat` in the above is `(100,1)`, while `y` is `(100,)`. So, when you do `tf.sub(y, y_hat)` you end up with a matrix of `(100,100)` which are all the possible combinations of subtractions between the two vectors. I don't know, but I guess that you managed to avoid this in the numpy code.

Two ways to fix your code:

```
y = np.array([[i * 0.4 + j * 0.9 + 1 for i, j in x]]).astype(np.float32).T
```

or

```
y_hat = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(x, w))
```

Although, that said, when I run this it still doesn't actually converge to the answer you want, but at least it's actually able to minimize the loss function.